# PCR cycle problem

Tags: genetics, dna, homework, pcr

IF I began a PCR cycle with 5 copies of a particular DNA section, and copied the section by PCR, for 6 cycles, how many copies of the DNA (include the originals) would I have by the end of these cycles? Explain or sketch out your reasoning.

Edit: I think it is 315 copies (5+10+20+40+80+160 = 315) after 6 cycles right?

Comment: What do you know about PCR? Especially about the double rates?

Comment: I think it is 315 copies after 6 cycles right? I did some research haha

Comment: Then you should redo you research. How do you come to 315?

Comment: uhh I did 5+10+20+40+80+160= 315

Comment: This is exponential - you double the number of molecules in each step. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCR ideally doubles the number of amplified DNA molecules in each cycle. So after the first step you have 10 molecules, after the second 20, the third 50 and so on. The formula for the calculation is:

n × 2<sup>cycles</sup> = number of molecules

n is the number of molecules you start your PCR with, cycles is the number of cycles used.

In your case this would be: 5 × 2<sup>6</sup> = 320 molecules of DNA.

Comment: hmmm so it goes 10, 20, then 50? How does it go to 50 for the third cycle?

Comment: No. It goes: 10 - 20 - 40 - 80 - 160 - 320. You double the amount of DNA molecules in each step, you are not adding them up.

Comment: so in the first cycle the 5 turns to 10? and then you start doubling it up? btw the formula up there I can't seem to find it on the internet, did your teacher teach it?

Comment: Yes, since you start with 5 DNA molecules, the first round goes up to 10.